# Make entire div a hyperlink

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

How do I make my entire `pad` div area a hyperlink?

http://jsfiddle.net/obxh7qpn/

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="pad">
    <div href="http://www.google.com" style="height:286px;width:286px;background:url('http://placehold.it/1x1') top center no-repeat;background-size:cover">
        <div>
            <span>View all</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href='http://www.google.com'>
<div class="pad">
    <div style="height:286px;width:286px;background:url('http://placehold.it/1x1') top center no-repeat;background-size:cover">
        <div>
            <span>View all</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

wrap a tag around the whole thing!

Comment: if you but the a inside the div and give style
display:block; width:100% would be better so the div.pad will have the same position as before

Comment: you can make it go away by hacking css, but this question did not ask for such

Comment: This is excellent. Semantically, is it sound? Or should I consider having a `<a>` tag before the closing `</div>` and force this to `width:100%;height:100%`?

Comment: depends what you want to do. It is sound semantically. please with fiddle and see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

Use "onclick=" event instead of href

```
<div onclick="document.location='http://www.google.com'> ...
```

Comment: there is no javascript tag in this question, but it should work?